# update nested json object using recursion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I'm trying to create an updated object from an existing object.
The sample object is:

```
// sample object
const testObj = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 2,
    d: {
      e: 3,
      f: {
        g: 4
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I want to create a new object from the above object with some concatenation of  each value:

```
// expected object
const expectedObject= {
  a: '1 a',
  b: {
    c: '2 a',
    d: {
      e: '3 a',
      f: {
        g: '4 a'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

here is my sample code:

```
let expectedObject = {};
const newObject = object => {
  Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      Object.keys(value).map(key => {
        value[key] = value[key] + " a";
        return value;
      });

      expectedObject[key] = value;
      //return newTest;
    } else {
      expectedObject[key] = value;
      return expectedObject;
    }
  });
  return expectedObject;
};
console.log(newObject(testObj));
```

the outcome in console is:

```
{a: 1, b: {…}}
a: 1
b:
c: "2 a"
d: "[object Object] a"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

I wanted to use recursion here and also tried it but no luck.
any help, thanks?

Comment: `const a = o => Object.keys(o).reduce((p, c) => ((p[c] = typeof o[c] === "object" ? a(o[c]) : o[c] + " a"), p), {});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using a modification of the original code to demonstrate what needed to be changed in order to make it work. You had some things switched up reading the `value` and setting the new one. Also I'm using the spread operator to clone the object before modifying it.

```js
const testObj = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 2,
    d: {
      e: 3,
      f: {
        g: 4
      }
    }
  }
};

const newObject = object => {
  const clonedObj = { ...object };
  const entries = Object.entries(clonedObj);

  entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      clonedObj[key] = newObject(value);
    } else {
      clonedObj[key] = value + " a";
    }
  });
  return clonedObj;
};
console.log(newObject(testObj));
console.log(testObj); // prove that the original object hasn't changed
```

Answer (score 7):

You could get a new object my mapping changed values and creating new objects.

```js
function map(object, fn) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, v && typeof v === 'object' ? map(v, fn) : fn(v)])
    );
}

var object = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: { e: 3, f: { g: 4 } } } },
    result = map(object, v => v + ' a');

console.log(result);
```

If you have arrays inside, you could add a check in advance and map the values.

```js
const
    map = fn => {
        const iter = v => v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? Array.isArray(v)
                ? v.map(iter)
                : Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(v).map(([k, v]) => [k, iter(v, fn)]))
            : fn(v);
        return iter;
    };

var object = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: { e: 3, f: { g: 4, k: [5, 6] } } } },
    addA = map(v => v + ' a'),
    result = addA(object);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I jus copied your code to `inex.js` file and run with `node index.js`, got the following error:
`TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function`

Comment: NB this will convert arrays `[]` to objects `{}` with string-based keys

Comment: It's also worth of saying that [`Object.fromEntries()` has limited compatibility and is only compatible with new browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @Yahya: But it's easy to write your own `fromEntries`, either by folding the results: `(entries) => entries .reduce ((a, [k, v]) => ({...a, [k]: v}), {})` or with `Object.assign`: `(entries) => Object.assign.apply (null, entries .map (([k, v]) => ({[k]: v})))`.  The latter is uglier, but [likely more efficient](https://www.richsnapp.com/blog/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern).

Comment: @ScottSauyet thank you very much for your explanation.
The answer from Nina Scholz is great, but I'm accepting the other answer because it meets the requirement without any error.

Comment: @Yahya: That's fine, but if you want to *learn* from an answer, look carefully at this one and the one from user633183,

Comment: @ScottSauyet I'm still trying to understand the answer from Nina and others as well, but it is not easy for me to digest at this moment.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply a refactoring of the answer from @user633183.  I like that approach a lot, but think it can be simplified by extracting two more reusable functions.  This started as a comment on that answer, but I thought it would be better to be explicit.

```js
const map = (f) => (a) => 
  a.map(f)

const mapObj = (f) => (o) => 
  Object .entries (o) .reduce ( (a, [k, v] ) => ({ ...a, [k]: f(v) }), {})

const traverse = (f) => (t) =>
  Array.isArray(t)
    ? map (traverse (f)) (t)
  : Object(t) === t 
    ? mapObj (traverse (f)) (t)
  : f (t)

const input =
  { a: [ 1, 11, 111 ], b: { c: 2, d: { e: [ 3, { f: { g: 4 } } ] } } }

const output =
  traverse(x => `${x} a`) (input)

console.log(output)
```

`mapObj` can be written in many different ways.  Here are two alternatives:

```js
const mapObj = (f = identity) => (o = {}) => 
  Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (o) .map (([ k, v ]) => [ k, f (v) ]))


const mapObj = (f = identity) => (o = {}) => 
  Object .assign .apply (null, Object .entries (o) .map (([ k, v ]) => ({ [k]: f (v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple recursive technique. It is similar to Nina's but it preserves arrays, if present in the structure.

1. If the input, `t`, is an array, create a new array by traversing each array value, `v`, with the traversing function, `f`
2. (inductive) Otherwise `t` is *not* an array. If `t` is an object, create a new object from key value pairs, `[ k, v ]`, by traversing each value, `v`, with the traversing function, `f`
3. (inductive) Otherwise `t` is *not* an array and `t` is *not* an object. This means `t` is either a primitive value, such as string, number, or `null`

Numbered comments below correspond to the explanation above -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const traverse = (f = identity, t = {}) =>
  Array.isArray(t)                         // 1
    ? Array.from(t, v => traverse(f, v))
: Object(t) === t                          // 2
    ? Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(t).map(([ k, v ]) => [ k, traverse(f, v) ]))
: f (t)                                    // 3

const input =
  { a: [ 1, 11, 111 ], b: { c: 2, d: { e: [ 3, { f: { g: 4 } } ] } } }

const output =
  traverse(x => `${x} a`, input)

console.log(output)
```

Comment: A suggested refactoring: pull out a `mapObject` function to use in part 2. It's a nicely reusable function and makes the main code quite clean

Comment: Note that `1` should be labeled as "inductive", not `3`.

Comment: thanks Scott. Your answer is a nice decomposition of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It works by building the solution at the same time as the input is traversed.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const testObj = { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: { e: 3, f: { g: 4 } } } };

const cloneAndModify = (obj) => objectScan(['**'], {
  breakFn: ({ property, value, isLeaf, context }) => {
    if (property === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    const ref = context[context.length - 1];
    if (!(property in ref)) {
      ref[property] = isLeaf ? `${value} a` : {};
    }
    context.push(ref[property]);
  },
  filterFn: ({ context }) => {
    context.pop();
  }
})(obj, [{}])[0];

const r = cloneAndModify(testObj);
console.log(r);
// => { b: { d: { f: { g: '4 a' }, e: '3 a' }, c: '2 a' }, a: '1 a' }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)