# How to find and change item in object array that can goes to a unknown depth in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm, logic

I have a object array like bellow, that can goes to an unknown depth. I also have a string array that contain path (keys).
`path keys ["29be61bd-3eee-7e5d-abb2-8791c02ab842", "19be61bd-3eee-7e8d-abb2-8791c02ab841", "19be61bd-3eee-7e8d-abb2-8791c02ab841"]`

```
[
  {
    "name": "background.png",
    "size": 3427,
    "__KEY__": "19be61bd-3eee-7e8d-abb2-8791c52av843",
    "content": "02610538-5847-4d50-b2cf-d4286bda2599",
    "isDirectory": false,
    "dateModified": "2022-07-06T14:33:57.634Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "background.png",
    "size": 3427,
    "__KEY__": "29be61bd-3eee-7e5d-abb2-8791c02ab842",
    "content": "7fbdd298-85b9-4839-8f75-58e0c7543ff1",
    "isDirectory": true,
    "dateModified": "2022-07-06T14:33:57.634Z",
    "items": [
        {
          "name": "47d10e6cc15beb354a4daadb4eb6a054 (1).gif",
          "size": 3427,
          "__KEY__": "19be61bd-3eee-7e8d-abb2-8791c02ab841",
          "isDirectory": true,
          "dateModified": "2022-07-05T19:58:04.707Z",
          "items": [
            {
              "name": "47d10e6cc15beb354a4daadb4eb6a054 (1).gif",
              "size": 3427,
              "__KEY__": "49be61bd-3eee-7e8d-abb2-8791c02ab843",
              "content": "adfkasbjfkjabsfjbas",
              "isDirectory": false,
              "dateModified": "2022-07-05T19:58:04.707Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "47d10e6cc15beb354a4daadb4eb6a055 (1).gif",
                "size": 3427,
                "__KEY__": "19be61bd-3eee-7e8d-abb2-8791c02ab841",
                "isDirectory": true,
                "dateModified": "2022-07-05T19:58:04.707Z",
                "items": [
                    {
                    "name": "47d10e6cc15beb354a4daadb4eb6a054 (1).gif",
                    "size": 3427,
                    "__KEY__": "19be61bd-3eee-7e8d-abb2-8791c02ab831",
                    "content": "dsvdsnakfna",
                    "isDirectory": false,
                    "dateModified": "2022-07-05T19:58:04.707Z"
                    }
                ]
              }
            
          ]
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "background.png",
    "size": 3427,
    "__KEY__": "background.png",
    "content": "4e977934-218f-4a18-a531-fc3d196bee7d",
    "isDirectory": false,
    "dateModified": "2022-07-06T14:33:57.634Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "background.png",
    "size": 3427,
    "__KEY__": "background.png",
    "isDirectory": true,
    "dateModified": "2022-07-06T14:33:57.634Z",
    "items": [
        {
        "name": "47d10e6cc15beb354a4daadb4eb6a054 (1).gif",
        "size": 3427,
        "__KEY__": "18be61bd-3eee-7e8d-abb2-8791c02ab831",
        "content": "dsvdsnakfna",
        "isDirectory": false,
        "dateModified": "2022-07-05T19:58:04.707Z"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to go to that path ( contains in the string array ) to the last folder and change recently added object in the "items" object array.
How I develop this logic? Can anyone help me to find a way for this? I am using Type script to develop this and need a effective method.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

Comment: also: [Access object child properties using a dot notation string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051975/access-object-child-properties-using-a-dot-notation-string)

Comment: why are there several elements with the same key in the same level? and which one to target?

Comment: This is what you're looking, many good solutions using recursive algorithms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184779/update-nested-json-object-using-recursion-in-javascript

Comment: @MisterJojo please consider "__KEY__" as a unique identifier.

Comment: @PsiKai: That question and its answers explain how to make changes with a function applied at the leaf nodes.  If I'm not mistaken, this is looking to change something at least one level higher.

Comment: @ScottSauyet yeah, I agree it's not exactly the same, but the core concept is there.  Happy to create a solution for OP, but didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Well If I understand your requirements correctly, here is what you would want to do:

1. Go through each key in the path list
2. Look for corresponding item in the current level of file structure
3. If found and its a folder containing items, move to the next level
4. If the current found item is a file, you may return an error may be if you want
5. Keep repeating above steps until you reach the last key
6. Once at the last level, make changes to the most recently added item

Here is how I would do it in TypeScript, since I mostly work in TypeScript:

```
// Start at the top level of the file structure
let currentFolder: Item[] = fileStructure;

// Iterate through each key in the provided path
for (const folderKey of path) {
    // Find the folder with the current key in the current level
    const currentFolderItem = currentFolder.find(folder => folder.__KEY__ === folderKey);

    // Check if the folder with the current key exists
    if (!currentFolderItem) {
        // Handle the case where the current key is not found in the current level
        return console.error(`Folder with key '${folderKey}' not found.`);
    }

    // Check if the current folder item is actually a folder (not a file)
    if (!currentFolderItem.items) {
        // Handle the case where the current item is a file and not a directory
        return console.error(`Item '${folderKey}' is not a folder.`);
    }

    // Move to the next level (the items inside the current folder)
    currentFolder = currentFolderItem.items;
}

// At this point, currentFolder contains the items array of the last folder in the path
// Now, you can modify the recently added object in the items array if it exists
if (currentFolder.length > 0) {
    // Assuming the recently added object is the last item in the array
    const recentlyAddedItemIndex = currentFolder.length - 1;
    currentFolder[recentlyAddedItemIndex] = { ...currentFolder[recentlyAddedItemIndex], ...updatedItem };
}
```